# select k size subset by picking only one value from each set

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

Given an array of n elements length where each element denotes set size, determine the number of ways you can select K size set.

> condition : You can't pick more than one element from one set. How to
>   solve this (any program)

Examples:

Input :

```
n = 4
k = 3
{1,2,1,1} Each value represents number of elements in each set
```

Output : 7

```
Example : 

{1},{2,3},{4},{5}

{1,2,4}
{1,2,5}
{1,3,4}
{1,3,5}
{1,4,5}
{2,4,5}
{3,4,5}
```

Code i tried but it returns 10 values which doesn't follow condition What mistake i done here?
they just gave subset length instead of actual subset. So i based on the sum of all the subset length i am forming a new array

```
count = 0

def printCombination(arr, n, r):
    global count
    data = [0]*r
    combinationUtil(arr, data, 0,
                    n - 1, 0, r)


def combinationUtil(arr, data, start,
                    end, index, r):
    global count

    if (index == r):

        for j in range(r):
            print(data[j], end=" ")
        print()
        count += 1
        return
    i = start
    while(i <= end and end - i + 1 >= r - index):
        data[index] = arr[i]
        combinationUtil(arr, data, i + 1,
                        end, index + 1, r)
        i += 1

in_val = [1,2,1,1] 
arr = list(range(1,sum(in_val)+1)) r = 3 
n = len(arr) 
printCombination(arr, n, r) 
print(count)
```

can we solve this with some formula with minimal time instead of simulating each subset and traversing through. Please throw some light on this or give me suggestion to proceed further.

Comment: Given condition "You can't pick more than one element from one set" why is {1,2,3} valid?  Isn't this choosing two values from set {2,3}?  Also isn't {1,3,4} and {1,4,3} the same set?

Comment: @DarrylG mistake has been corrected

Comment: same set should not be allowed

Comment: @johnwilson--created a function for the count (since you mentioned only needing the number of ways).  Let me know if you need the actual sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all input sets are disjoint, a dynamic programming approach allows us to calculate the number of such combinations in `O(n)` time, where `n` is the number of sets (assuming input sets' cardinalities are bounded above by a constant; otherwise, the time complexity is `O(n, max_size)` where `max_size` is the cardinality of an input set with maximum size).

```
import random # testing
from functools import lru_cache # memoization

xs = [{1},{2,3},{4},{5}]
k = 3
sizes = [len(x) for x in xs]
# [1, 2, 1, 1]

# dynamic programming approach
def count_combinations(sizes, k=3):
  @lru_cache(None)
  def f(n, k):
    if (n < k) or (k < 0):
      # no combination possible
      return 0
    elif n == k:
      # return product sizes[:n]
      res = 1
      for x in sizes[:n]:
        res *= x
      return res
    else:
      # recursive memoized call
      # f(n-1, k-1) ways to select k-1 elts from n-1 sets
      # times size of n-1'st set (counting from 0)
      # plus f(n-1, k) ways to select k elts from n-1 sets
      return sizes[n-1] * f(n-1, k-1) + f(n-1, k)
  return f(len(sizes), k)

# assert count_combs(sizes, k=k) == count_combinations(sizes, k)
```

---

```
# larger benchmark
n = 25
k = n // 2
xs = [{random.randint(0, n) for i in  range(n)} for _ in range(n)]
sizes = [len(x) for x in xs]

%time count_combs(sizes, k)          # O(n choose k), 8.6 s
%timeit count_combinations(sizes, k) # O(n), 112 µs
```

This avoids considering all possible combinations of size k explicitly, dropping complexity form `O(n choose k)` to `O(n)`.

Comment: Impressive speedup over my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Determine the number of ways you can select K size set.

```
from itertools import combinations
from functools import reduce

def count_combs(arr, k):
  if k > len(arr):
    return 0  # Not possible
  elif k == len(arr):
    return reduce(lambda a, b: a*b, arr) # multiply values in arr
  else:
    """sum of answer to each sub-set of arr of size k
       subsets of arr of size k are combinations(arr, k)"""
    return sum(count_combs(x, k) for x in combinations(arr, k))
```

**Test**

```
arr = [1, 2, 1, 1]
print(count_combs(arr, 3))
# Outputs 7

arr = [1, 1, 1, 1]
print(count_combs(arr, 3))
# Outputs 4

arr = [1, 1, 1, 2]
print(count_combs(arr, 2))
# Output 9
```

**Explanation**

Three cases

1. k > len(arr): Not possible, so answer is 0
2. k == len(arr): Its the number of ways we can take one element at a time from each array index, which is the product of the values of the array arr.
3. k < len(arr): We sum the answer of all subsets of arr of size k select k (i.e. as sub-problems). Then we sum the solution count to each of these sub-problems. The solution to each sub-problem is known from step 2 above.